# "Stored Procedures Invoked/sec" counter always increasing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, monitoring, service-broker

We've implemented some feature using service broker and deployed recently on production. I am observing that "Stored Procedures Invoked/sec" counter is always increasing. However, I can see that other counters like Tasks Running etc are stable. Why Stored Procedures Invoked/sec not stick to a range?

Comment: Just observed that "Tasks Started/sec" is also not stable. It's also increasing along with "Stored procesures invoked/sec".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different types of performance counters, five of which are used by SQL Server (at least in terms of what you will find in the `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` DMV). You can see this via the following query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT [cntr_type]
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
ORDER BY [cntr_type];
```

Returns:

```
65792
272696576
537003264
1073874176
1073939712
```

Those values mean:

- [Noncomputational Counter Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392713.aspx)

  - `65792` == **PERF_COUNTER_LARGE_RAWCOUNT** == "Raw counter value that does not require calculations, and represents one sample which is the last observed value only."
- [Counter Algorithm Counter Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389384.aspx)

  - `272696576` == **PERF_COUNTER_BULK_COUNT** == "Average number of operations completed during each second of the sample interval."
  - `1073874176` == **PERF_AVERAGE_BULK** == "Number of items processed, on average, during an operation. This counter type displays a ratio of the items processed (such as bytes sent) to the number of operations completed, and requires a base property with PERF_AVERAGE_BASE as the counter type."
- [Base Counter Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384811.aspx)

  - `1073939712` == **PERF_LARGE_RAW_BASE** == "Base value found in the calculation of PERF_RAW_FRACTION"
- [Basic Algorithm Counter Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384813.aspx)

  - `537003264` == **PERF_LARGE_RAW_FRACTION** == "Ratio of a subset to its set as a percentage. This counter type displays the current percentage only, not an average over time."

You can find more info in the following blog post: [Interpreting the counter values from sys.dm_os_performance_counters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2013/09/23/interpreting-the-counter-values-from-sys-dm_os_performance_counters/)

The **Stored Procedures Invoked/sec** counters in the **SQLServer:Broker Activation** category are of type **272696576** (i.e. "PERF_COUNTER_BULK_COUNT"). These values are cumulative. You need to capture a value into a variable, wait for N seconds (i.e. `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'; -- 30 seconds`), capture a second value, and then divide the difference between the values by N (i.e. `SELECT  (@var2 - @var1) / 30.0;`). For example:

```sql
DECLARE @Sample1 BIGINT,
        @Sample2 BIGINT,
        @Time1 DATETIME,
        @Time2 DATETIME;

SELECT @Sample1 = [cntr_value],
       @Time1 = GETDATE()
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE [object_name] = N'SQLServer:Databases' -- SQLServer:Broker Activation
AND   [counter_name] = N'Transactions/sec' -- Stored Procedures Invoked/sec
AND   [instance_name] = N'_Total';

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30.000'; -- 30 second pause/sleep

SELECT @Sample2 = [cntr_value],
       @Time2 = GETDATE()
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE [object_name] = N'SQLServer:Databases' -- SQLServer:Broker Activation
AND   [counter_name] = N'Transactions/sec' -- Stored Procedures Invoked/sec
AND   [instance_name] = N'_Total';

SELECT (@Sample2 - @Sample1) AS [Difference],
       (DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @Time1, @Time2) / 1000.0) AS [Seconds],
       (@Sample2 - @Sample1) / (DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @Time1, @Time2) / 1000.0);
```

Comment: You mean to say it's a cumulative figure and not per sec?

Comment: @AshwiniMohan Yes. Please see my updated answer for details and example code.

Comment: Then why it is called as "Stored Procedures Invoked/sec"?  Better it would have been called "Total Number of Stored Procedures Invoked".

Comment: @AshwiniMohan Probably because it is sampled each second. If you don't like the name, you can bring that up to Microsoft on https://connect.microsoft.com . However, the name -- good or bad -- doesn't affect the functionality. The information I provided is accurate and will allow you to get the information you are looking for.

Comment: I know you provided the accurate information and I trust you. The reasons you've given, that makes sense to me. I was just wondering about the performance counter name, nothing else.